# CSS3 transformation not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to rotate div elements when user clicks on div element (card).

To do that I am using JavaScript that adds class that rotate divs (using jQuery).

Problem is that when user clicks on DIV (or card), that div doesn't rotate

Here is my code that I am using:

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YbL3Z/)

HTML:

```
<div id="boxcard" align="center">
            <div id="card1"><img src="http://img6.uploadhouse.com/fileuploads/17699/17699263b01721074bf094aa3bc695aa19c8d573.png" class=""></div>
            <div id="card2"><img src="http://img9.uploadhouse.com/fileuploads/17699/176992615db99bb0fd652a2e6041388b2839a634.png" class=""></div>
            <div id="card3"><img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/reclusekc/kulo/96/Skull-1-icon.png"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#boxcard {
    z-index: 1;
    display: table;
        margin: 0px auto;
    width: auto;
}

#boxcard div{
    float: left;
    width: 100;
    height: 120;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 4px solid #EE872A;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
  background: #B1B1B1;
    z-index: 2;
}
#boxcard > div:nth-child(6n+1) {
    clear: both;
}
#boxcard div img {
    /*display: none;*/
    border-radius: 10px;
    z-index: 3;
}

#boxcard div img.flip{

  transform: rotateY(180deg);
   display:inline-block;

}
```

JavaScript:

```
var ImgOpened;
var BoxOpened;
var CurrentOpened;
$(document.getElementById("card1")).click(OpenCard);
$(document.getElementById("card2")).click(OpenCard);
$(document.getElementById("card3")).click(OpenCard);
function OpenCard() {
        var id = $(this).attr("id");
        var img = document.querySelector("#" + id + " img");
        img.classList.toggle("flip");

        if (ImgOpened == "") {
            BoxOpened = id;
            ImgOpened = $("#" + id + " img").attr("src");
        }
        else {
            CurrentOpened = $("#" + id + " img").attr("src");
            if (ImgOpened != CurrentOpened) {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    document.querySelector("#" + id + " img").classList.toggle("flip");
                    document.querySelector("#" + BoxOpened + " img").classList.toggle("flip");
                    BoxOpened = "";
                    ImgOpened = "";
                }, 400);
            } 
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why do you think, you cannot link jsfiddles without writing code? Right. Because this is bad. If the link stops working, your question is worthless. Please post the essential parts of your code as well.

Comment: sorry for that. I updated my question @Christoph

Comment: Have a look at the console: `Uncaught ReferenceError: ImgOpened is not defined`. There lies your problem.

Comment: I forgot to include it here but I have those variables defined isnide my code

Comment: Your code has multiple errors. I attempted to fix them one by one but had to abandon it, since I don't know about your application logic. Try using Chrome Dev console.

Comment: $(document.getElementById("card1") it's a mix between js and jquery. $('#card1') it's enough. Then click(OpenCard) has to be: click(OpenCard())

Comment: @MrPk Your first comment is correct, when using jQuery one should  directly hand over the selector string: `$("#card1")`. Your second comment is wrong however - you want to hand over a function reference, not the return value, so `click(OpenCard)` is the correct way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mbanandetoro6/aMkBd/1/)**

You need to add prefixes like below, 
all browsers dose not support all features of css3, for getting most browser support you need to add prefixes.

[MORE INFO ON BROWSER PREFIX](http://webdesign.about.com/od/css/a/css-vendor-prefixes.htm)

```
#boxcard div img {
    /*display: none;*/
    border-radius: 10px;
    z-index: 3;
    -o-transition-duration:.5s;
    -moz-transition-duration:.5s;
    -webkit-transition-duration:.5s;
    transition-duration:.5s;
}

#boxcard div img.flip{
-o-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
   display:inline-block;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YbL3Z/3/)

```
#boxcard div img.flip{
transform:rotate(180deg);
-ms-transform:rotate(180deg); /* IE 9 */
-webkit-transform:rotate(180deg);
display:inline-block;
}
```

The transform property is supported in Internet Explorer 10 and Firefox.

Internet Explorer 9 supports an alternative, the -ms-transform property (2D transforms only).

Opera, Chrome and Safari support an alternative, the -webkit-transform property

Answer (score 0):

I slightly modified your code

```
#boxcard div img.flip{

  transform: rotate(180deg);
   display:inline-block;

}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/e2n4M/)